# Python via Windows Task Scheduler can't import installed packages

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a Python-Script that I want to run using the Windows Task Scheduler. I am able to start the script, but once I add

> import pandas as pd

the script fails to complete. I therefore assume that the call to the environment is set incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

I'm using Anaconda 3.7.4 x64 on Win10 x64. All my packages are installed into the anaconda base environment, there is no utilization of venv (due to corporate guidelines).

MWE:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
input("Hello")
import numpy as np
print("done")
```

When starting from the IDE, i get (pressing a key after Hello)

```
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
C:\Prog\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
Hello
done
```

When starting as scheduled task, using the

> C:\Prog\Anaconda3\python.exe

as executable and the full path to the script as options, my result is

```
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
C:\Prog\Anaconda3\python.exe
Hello
```

and the script finishes unexpectedly. Therefore, I assume that the script crashes when trying to import pandas. This works on the version that is called from the IDE, where the same executable (python.exe) is linked. Note however, that the executable that I retrieve from sys.executable seems to be pythonw.exe.

How do I configure my task correctly, so that it will successfully import pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to launch a script with task scheduler is by using a batch file ([link](https://datatofish.com/batch-python-script/)) and launching the batch file in the "actions" section of task scheduler. In your Batch file you specify your Python executable and your script like this:

"C://users/document/path/to/python.exe" "C://users/document/path/to/scripts/script.py"
pause

If this isn't clear enough, I invite you to read this post: [Running a Batch File at a Scheduled Time](https://windows.tips.net/T013223_Running_a_Batch_File_at_a_Scheduled_Time.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea, however, this is not what I'm trying to solve. I can run scripts via task scheduler fine, its just that my environment seems to be unavailable.

Comment: Do you have an error message to share? Or can you add an input statement at the end instead of a print. I think your script works fine but finishes after printing the "done" statement by closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever finds this thread for years to come, I was facing the same issue when trying to run python script with windows task scheduler and the script would stop at one of my import lines. The issue here is you probably have a virtual environment and need to run python from that virtual environment. The directory would look something like this:
"c:/users/the/code/folder/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"

Ultimately, the solution is to create a batch script, and similarly to the earlier answer specify the executable and your python script like this:

"c:/users/the/code/folder/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/users/the/code/folder/script.py"